# Best way to infer type from a List<Number> list?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, numbers

So I have a `List<Number>` that contains both Doubles and Integers, I have to loop through the List and randomize each Number by +- 25%

This is an example similar to my code:

```
public class ListTester {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ListTester lt = new ListTester();        
    }   

    public ListTester(){
        int a = 1;
        int b = 2;
        double d = 3.5;
        randomizableStats = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(a, b, d));        
        randomizeStats();
    }

    protected List <Number> randomizableStats;    

    protected void randomizeStats(){
        List<Number> randomizedStats = new ArrayList<>();

        Random r = new Random();
        for (Number n : randomizableStats){             
            int l = r.nextInt(1);
            int i = r.nextInt(25);
            if (l == 1){
                if (n instanceof Integer) {
                    Integer n2 = (Integer) n;
                    n2 = n2 + (i / 100 * n2) + 1;
                    randomizedStats.add(n2);
                } else if (n instanceof Double) {                    
                    Double n2 = (Double) n;
                    double d = (double) i;
                    n2 = n2 + (d / 100 * n2);
                    randomizedStats.add(n2);
                }
            } else {
                if (n instanceof Integer) {
                    Integer n2 = (Integer) n;
                    n2 = n2 - (i / 100 * n2) - 1;
                    randomizedStats.add(n2);
                } else if (n instanceof Double) {
                    Double n2 = (Double) n;
                    double d = (double) i;
                    n2 = n2 - (d / 100 * n2);
                    randomizedStats.add(n2);
                }
            }             
        }      
        for (Number n : randomizableStats){
            System.out.print(n);
        }
        for (Number n : randomizedStats){
            System.out.print(n);
        }
    }
}
```

The question is, is there a better way to write this, without having to go through a forced casting to Integer\Double complicating everything with additional if statements?

Comment: Do you know that you're not changing the values of the list, right? Because `Integer` and `Double` are immutables.

Comment: I hope you realize that `(i / 100 * n2)` will be calculated using `Integer` arithmetic.

Comment: Yeah that's what I get for writing code from my mind instead of copy pasting it...

Comment: When you use `for-each` loop you are operating with **values** of (not **references** to) the collection you iterate through. Your code will not make any changes to the list.

Comment: For this case it would be better using `BigDecimal` instead of `Integer` and `Double`. Besides, you would need to create a new `List` for this, or use an array instead.

Comment: `c` is not defined. `double d = 3,5;` will  not compile.

Comment: @PM77-1 The loop does operate on references to the collection items, but all references refer to immutable `Number` objects.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen - May be I used a wrong terminology, but I insist that `for (Object n : objectCollection) { n = null}` will have no impact on `objectCollection`, since `for-each` is just a syntactic sugar for `Iterator`-based loop.

Comment: I fixed the code so that it would compile and work, now is there an answer to the question?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind converting everything to double, you can use [`Number.doubleValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#doubleValue()).

```
for (Number n : randomizables) {
    int i = r.nextInt(1);
    int l = r.nextInt(24) + 1;

    if (i == 1) {
        double d = n.doubleValue();
        d = d + (d * l/100);

        // do something with d
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need to put them back in the list as they were since they are used as ints and doubles to build other objects in other parts of the code. In this case I would still have to cast the Double back to Integer.

Comment: @AngeloAlvisi - Do you realize that (for example) `2 +/- 25%` cannot be reasonably expressed as integer?

Comment: Sorry to say so, but the design of your application smells. Bad.

Comment: Yes I do realize the flaws in the code, I wrote this just for the question. I just need to understand if there's a way I can make java and not the loop do the job of infering whether n is an Integer or a Double.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as a design exercise one solution to avoid using **instaceof**, which in general is discourage (I'll comment on that latter), one solution is to use polymorphism. In your case for instance, you can create the following classes:

```
public abstract class NewNumber {
    protected Number number;
    public abstract NewNumber multiply(int m);
    public Number toNumber() {
        return this.number;
    }
}

public class NewNumberInt extends NewNumber{
    public NewNumberInt(Integer number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    @Override
    public NewNumber multiply(int m) {
        int out = this.number.intValue()*m;
        return new NewNumberInt(out);
    }
}

public class NewNumberDou extends NewNumber{
    public NewNumberDou(Double number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    @Override
    public NewNumber multiply(int m) {
        double out = this.number.doubleValue()*m;
        return new NewNumberDou(out);
    }
}
```

With this, your program can be rewritten in the following way

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
double d = 3.5;
List<NewNumber> randomizables = new ArrayList<NewNumber>();
randomizables.add(new NewNumberInt(a));
randomizables.add(new NewNumberInt(b));
randomizables.add(new NewNumberDou(d));

// Example on how to convert from NewNumber to Number 
List<Number> randomizablesNumber = new ArrayList<Number>();
for (NewNumber numNew:randomizables) randomizablesNumber.add(numNew.toNumber());

public void randomize(){
    Random r = new Random();
    for (NewNumber n : randomizables){
        int i = r.nextInt(1);
        int l = r.nextInt(24)+1;
        if (i == 1){
            NewNumber n2 = n.multiply(l/100);
        }
    }
}
```

The question is whether it is worth it to write all this just to avoid the usage of **instanceof**. From a design point of view of course it is and I personally prefer to spend 2 more minutes but have something well done, than just save these minutes and have something that is not nice. However, I understand that sometimes simple is best...

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I need ints to be ints in that list, NewNumber doesn't cut it

Comment: If you need this, check the edition on my answer. I added the method **toNumber** that return a Number. Then, I placed an example on how to convert a list of NewNumber to a list of Number. Hope this help

Comment: I resolved by not passing the fields to a list at all. I will have them multiplied singularly at construction time.